# Replacing strings between | | with RegEx using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am fetching some data from an API. One of the results is this string:

| Experience Points | Level | Proficiency Bonus |

I've been trying to use RegEx with replace() to have each string between | | in a  tag. So far I was able to have the first and last inside the tag, but I fail to have the middle string inside the tag. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and maybe help me with a solution? I've been stuck on this for days. I'd really appreciate it.

This is what I have done so far:

```
replace(/\|\s(\D*?)\|/g, "<span>$1</span>")
```

It gives me the following result:

```
<span> Experience Points </span> Level <span> Proficiency Bonus </span>
```

This is what I expect:

```
<span> Experience Points </span> <span> Level </span> <span> Proficiency Bonus </span>
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your RegEx pattern...

Do it in 2 passes:

```
// 1st pass
var str = "| Experience Points | Level | Proficiency Bonus |";
var intermediateResult = str.replace(/\|\s(\D*?)\|/g, "</span> <span> $1</span> <span>");

// intermediate result:
// </span> <span> Experience Points </span> <span> Level </span> <span> Proficiency Bonus </span> <span>

// 2nd pass
var result = intermediateResult.replace(/^(<\/span> )|( <span>)$/g, "")

// result:
// <span> Experience Points </span> <span> Level </span> <span> Proficiency Bonus </span>
```

or in 1 line:

```
var str = "| Experience Points | Level | Proficiency Bonus |";

var result = str.replace(/\|\s(\D*?)\|/g, "</span> <span> $1</span> <span>").replace(/^(<\/span> )|( <span>)$/g, "")
```

Using a different RegEx pattern:

```
var result = str.replace(/\|/g, "<span> </span>").replace(/^<span>|<\/span>$/g, "")
```

Comment: OMG! You are a life saver! It worked perfectly. I was about to ask to @kol if I could use his solution with RegEx and I saw your solution and it fit like a glove. Thank you both for help me to understand better my code. I am just starting in the JavaScript world and still have a lot to learn. Thank you ALL!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = "| Experience Points | Level | Proficiency Bonus |";
const output = input.split(/\s*\|\s*/).filter(s => s.length > 0).map(s => `<span>${s}</span>`).join("");
console.log(output);
```

...or simply:

```js
const input = "| Experience Points | Level | Proficiency Bonus |";
const output = input.replaceAll(" | ", "</span><span>").replace("| ", "<span>").replace(" |", "</span>");
console.log(output);
```

If you need spaces between the `<span>`s, then:

- in the 1st solution, replace `.join("")` with `.join(" ")`, and
- in the 2nd solution, replace `"</span><span>"` with `"</span> <span>"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I really appreciate it. The way to go was the 2nd solution. Because I have other data from the API at the same variable, when I used the 1st solution it replaced all the data. With the 2nd solution I was able to isolate what I want. I am actually trying to insert these strings in a table. I think it will be possible now. Thanks again!